# Javascript/HTML variable is undefined (global var)

Tags: javascript, html

Ok I can't seem to figure out why this variable is coming back undefined in my alert box. What am I missing here?

```
<html>
<script src="xslt.js"></script>
<script>
var file;
var objecturl;
var files;
var filename="filename goes here";
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    file = files[0];
    filename = file.name;
}
function submit() {
alert(filename);
}
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
Select your XML/CCD File(s):<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="View CCD" onclick="submit();" />
<div id="transformResult"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't, it comes back "filename goes here"

Comment: Weird, for me it comes back as undefined.

Comment: @Kyle what browser are you using?

Comment: If I [fix the error](http://jsbin.com/cayehofo/1/edit?html,output) with the script appearing before the input it tries to modify, then it comes back with the file name of the file I picked, so I still can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Chrome browser, which has worked in the past with other code I've written similar to this.

Comment: Files is defined but files[0] is undefined. Dude use window.files to set the global var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
var file;
var objecturl;
var files;
var filename="filename goes here";
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    file = files[0];
    filename = file.name;
}
function submit() {
alert(filename);
}
</script>

Select your XML/CCD File(s):<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="View CCD" onclick="submit();" />
<div id="transformResult"></div>

<script>
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

Notice I moved the addEventListener to a script that runs after the elements are loaded in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the `input` field to be in the dom before calling `getElementById`, hence `filename` is not set.

Comment: While that is an error in the code in the question, it doesn't explain the result that is described there.

Comment: Alright, so what would be the best way to rearrange this so that it is loaded in the correct order.

Comment: you should put it in a load handler.

Comment: Move the script element to after the input element.